# Is it possible to implement a MCU with SimpleWebRTC and signalmaster? How?

Tags: webrtc, simplewebrtc, signalmaster

I have a peer to peer videoconference app using simpleWebRTC and signalmaster for signaling. When more than 4 users connects the stress it causes on the network and the TURN server is too big, so I was thinking, is it possible to implement a MCU in this case? What would it take to do it?

Comment: Are you trying to create a group call with 4+ participants, or it's a scenario with 2+ peer-to-peer calls (2 participants per call)?

Comment: @jamix I want to support more than 4 participants. I'm also interested in an SFU (Selective Forwarding Unit) and I want to know which solution people think is the best for my case, SFU or MCU, and what approach should I have when implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

For more than 4 participants, full mesh (connecting each participant with everyone else peer-to-peer) is impractical. If there are `n` participants, then each of them needs to have `n - 1` outgoing and `n - 1` incoming video streams, which quickly saturates the bandwidth, especially on mobile.

An SFU, for example [Janus](https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/), forwards packets between call participants. The advantage of the SFU for group calls is that each participant needs to push their video stream only once - to the SFU - which then forwards it to everyone else. There are still `n - 1` incoming streams for each participant though.

An MCU is capable of combining multiple video streams into one, so each participant ends up with `1` outgoing video stream and `1` incoming composite video stream. To produce a composite video stream out of `n - 1` individual ones, an MCU needs to re-encode video in realtime, which makes it a CPU hog.

I would suggest giving Janus (SFU) a try first and seeing how that works for you.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at Janus, but is it possible to implement it in a scenario like mine (SimpleWebRTC + signalmaster)? If so, what would it take?

Comment: It looks like SimpleWebRTC is peer-to-peer only. Please see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48093080/is-jitsi-videobridge-compatible-with-other-webrtcs-api-or-do-we-have-to-use-it/48093761#48093761