# Is jitsi-videobridge compatible with other webrtc's API or do we have to use it with meet?

Tags: webrtc, jitsi, simplewebrtc

I want to implement a SFU in my WebRTC videoconference app. Jitsi Videobridge seems like a good option, but can I use it with any webrtc API? For instance, I'm using SimpleWebRTC, is it possible to implement a SFU in this case with Jitsi Videobridge? If so, how? If not, what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

From [this thread](https://github.com/andyet/SimpleWebRTC/issues/356) it looks like Jitsi Videobridge support is not implemented in SimpleWebRTC, which is peer-to-peer only:

> the jitsi videobridge. But it's not integrated with simplewebrtc (which is mainly p2p/full mesh) so you'll have to go for something like https://github.com/otalk/stanza.io and https://github.com/otalk/mod_muc_focus which we use for talky.io

Jitsi "talks" XMPP so that's why [stanza.io](https://github.com/legastero/stanza.io) is suggested.